# In aspx, fileUpload is alway null after postBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a fileUpload in an aspx webpage. When a user chooses a JPEG file and clicks a button, I cannot get JPEG file. fileUpload always return null. I think it gets nulled on postback. How can I fix this?

my code is like below

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream fs = fileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can we see your ASPX markup ?

Comment: Did my answer help you out, can you let me know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your ASPX markup it is difficult to say precisely.

Your ASPX markup should be similar to:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPost" OnClick="btnPostClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

C# Code-behind:

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
    }
}
```